# android spinner in recyclerView does not work properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, spinner, adapter

I am trying to use Spinner ( 3 dots with dropdown menu) in my recyclerView, but when I load this recyclerView function *onItemSelected* is called automatically and later when I press on item it is not called anymore. Here is my code in adapter:

```
       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.my_listing_item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ((SaleAdapter.SalesViewHolder) holder).overflow.setAdapter(adapter);

            ((SaleAdapter.SalesViewHolder) holder).overflow.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position) + " item is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

}

  public static class SalesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public LinearLayout overflowLayout;
      public Spinner overflow;

      public SalesViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
          super(itemView);

          overflowLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_overflow_layout);
          overflow = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_overflow);
      }
     }
```

Here is code of View:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item_overflow_layout"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_more_vert_24dp_grey"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/list_item_overflow"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know what is the problem here with my code? Should I export *setOnItemSelectedListener* somewhere else?

Comment: So each item in the recyclerview includes a spinner which wants to mimic the menu dropdown?

Comment: Tomas, yes, you are right

Comment: I believe it's a better idea to implement a pop up menu for every recyclerview item instead of a spinner.

Comment: As the docs say "Providing a drop-down similar to Spinner that does not retain a persistent selection."

Comment: Tomas, but popup menu requires clear coordinates for each item, it is not possible in recycler view. Maybe do you know any examples of popup menu which does not require?

Comment: What do you mean by 'clear coordinates"? From what I understand you want each item of your recyclerview to include a menu, right?

Comment: Tomas, yes, never mind about coordinates, do you know any exampes of popup?

Comment: I believe I do, let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use a [PopUpMenu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#PopupMenu) for each item in the list. Have an `ImageView` instead of the `Spinner` which will display a "3 dot" icon. When someone clicks the dots the PopUpMenu will... pop up!

In steps:

1)Replace the `Spinner` in the xml layout with an `ImageView` which will display the three dots icon.

2) Define a listener class inside your `RecyclerView.Adapter<SalesViewHolder>` and save an instance there.

3) Inside `SalesViewHolder` set an `OnClickListener` to responds to clicks.

4) Pop up from the Activity.

Your new adapter should look something like this

```
class SalesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SalesViewHolder>{
    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener{
        void onMenuItemClicked(ImageView view);
    }

    private OnMenuItemClickListener listener;

    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public static class SalesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout overflowLayout;
        public ImageView menu;

    public SalesViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);

        overflowLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_overflow_layout);
        menu= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_id);
        // Make sure to enable lambdas
        menu.setOnClickListener( (view) -> {
            if( listener != null ){
                listener.onMenuItemClicked(view);
            }
        }
    }
     }

}
```

Your activity must implement the OnMenuItemClickListener and may look something like this

```
class YourActivity extends Activity implements SalesAdapter.OnMenuItemClickListener{

    // Don't forget to set the listener to the adapter,  let's suppose that happens in onCreate()
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arg){
        SalesAdapter adapter = new SalesAdapter();
        adapter.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuItemClicked(ImageView menu){
        showPopUp(menu);
    }

    private void showPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
    }

}
```

Don't forget to supply menu actions etc... as mentioned [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu).